# undefined method in controller from entity symfony

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Hello I try to create an entity when another linked entity is created via a postPersist method but I find myself making this error someone knows why? I can not find the reason.

In **ClientAdmin.php** like the Sonata Documentation advice to do. [Sonata Doc](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/saving_hooks.html)

```
public function postPersist($client)
{

    if ($client instanceof Client )
    {
        $money = new Money();
        $money->setClient($client);
        $money->setSurname($client->getSurname());
        $money->setFirstname($client->getFirstname());
    }
}
```

**Client.php :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Money", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $money;


/**
 * Set money
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Money $money
 *
 * @return Client
 */
public function setMoney(\AppBundle\Entity\Money $money )
{
    $this->money = $money;
}

/**
 * Get money
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Money
 */
public function getMoney()
{
    return $this->money;
}
```

**The error :**

*Solution :*
 Working but nothing is create is the table "Money" so i'm supposed it because I don't persist and flush it but I can't do it in it . :/

***Working on Symfony 3.3 with SonataAdmin 3.19***

Thanks in advance !

**Edit** : Solution found :

```
public function postPersist($client)
{
    $em = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');


    if ($client instanceof Client )
    {
        $money = new Money();
        $money->setClient($client);
        $money->setSurname($client->getSurname());
        $money->setFirstname($client->getFirstname());
        $em->persist($money);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is totally wrong.

```
$this->setMoney(new Money()); }
```

this means you call setMoney method of the class ClientAdminController(which is $this)

but ClientAdminController does not have the method setMoney(Money). You have to call it on a Client instance.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by " call it on a Client instance"

Comment: $this is an instance of ClientAdminController. But the method is defined in the class Client, so you have call it on something that is an instance of Client

Comment: Ok but i have no idea how to do it. I just learning php and symfony.

Comment: is very hard to help if you do not know the basics. please find a tutorial on object oriented programming in php.

Comment: No i know how to do it normally but not with sonataAdmin cause I don't have access to the controller of the entity.

Comment: I'm trying to use     `public function postPersist( $client ){
        $client->setMoney(new Money());
    }` in the ClientAdmin.php but still have a bug

Comment: I try to update and lear a bit more about it. Can you have a look on the "new" question ?